# Two xml compare and get the difference

Tags: xml, comparison

**My code is:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.List;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DetailedDiff;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Difference;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlCompare {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException,
    IOException { 

        // reading two xml file to compare in Java program 
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("D:/SasmitaDas/xml/source.xml"); 
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("D:/SasmitaDas/xml/target.xml"); 
        // using BufferedReader for improved performance 
        BufferedReader source = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis1)); 
        BufferedReader target = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2)); 
        //configuring XMLUnit to ignore white spaces 
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true); 
        //comparing two XML using XMLUnit in Java 
        List differences = compareXML(source, target); 
        //showing differences found in two xml files 
        printDifferences(differences); 
        } 

    public static List compareXML(Reader source, Reader target) throws  SAXException, 
    IOException{

        //creating Diff instance to compare two XML files 
        Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(source, target); 
        //for getting detailed differences between two xml files 
        DetailedDiff detailXmlDiff = new DetailedDiff(xmlDiff); 
        return detailXmlDiff.getAllDifferences(); 
        }

    public static void printDifferences(List differences){ 

        int totalDifferences = differences.size(); 
        System.out.println("===============================");
        System.out.println("Total differences : " + totalDifferences);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(Object difference : differences){
            System.out.println(difference); 
            }
        } 
    }
```

**I am getting error as:**

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
>   1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.     at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.java:382)  at
>   org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.java:369)  at
>   org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.(Diff.java:101)   at
>   seleniumCode.XmlCompare.compareXML(XmlCompare.java:39)    at
>   seleniumCode.XmlCompare.main(XmlCompare.java:30)
>
> please help on this

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your XML file, no prob with the code